# Horror movie with a cave carving of a demon possessing a man, involves a woman falling to her death

Tags: story-identification, movie, horror

It's an old film made in say the early millennium. It features a cave carving of a demonic-looking face that possesses this man to kill for it. It is set among a camp site or a cabin.

One of the scenes involves a female either jumping to her death or being thrown to her death, either way that's one of the scenes in it.

The ending had a close up of the demonic carving before the credits rolled.

Comment: Some things you should know:  **A** We add the [tag:story-identification] tag for questions like this; **B** are you certain that the movie was made in the early 2000s, or was that when you saw it?

Comment: Thanks you for the added tag, and as for the year of release or viewing, it could be either one of them. All I know is that the ending had a close up of the demonic carving before the credits rolled

Comment: Jeez, are movies made "in the early millennium" really "old"?  Especially from the POV of a question from 2018?

Answer (score 3):

If the movie centers around a small boy you might be thinking of *The Omen* (2006). There are two scenes actually that involve a woman falling and the movie starts with the excavation of a statue. The camp site or cabin does not fit though.

From [IMDb](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0466909/?ref_=nv_sr_srsg_3):

> When the Vatican observatory Priest sees the appearance of a comet, the Church is sure that it confirms the eve of the Armageddon. Meanwhile, the U.S. President's godson Robert Thorn (Liev Schreiber) is informed in the maternity ward in Rome by Father Spiletto (Giovanni Lombardo Radice) that his wife Katherine (Julia Stiles) has just lost her baby and she had troubles with her uterus and would not have another pregnancy. Spiletto suggests to Robert that another just-born child that lost his mother could be the substituted for his son, and Robert accepts the child and gives him the name of "Damien". Robert is promoted to ambassador in London after a tragic accident. When Damien's nanny (Amy Huck) commits suicide during his birthday party, a substitute, Mrs. Baylock (Mia Farrow), comes to work and live with the family. Through the years, Katherine realizes that Damien is evil, while Robert is contacted by Father Brennan (Pete Postlethwaite), who tells him that Damien is the son of devil. When the Priest dies in a bizarre accident, photographer Keith Jennings (David Thewlis) shows evidence to Robert that the boy is the Antichrist. They travel to the town of Megiddo to learn how the boy can be stopped.

Answer (score 0):

It's "The Empty Man"

Comment: Can you [edit] in any reasons as to why you believe this is what the OP is looking for? Please see [answer] and the [help] for some helpful information